# how to modify raw html: table structure in printjs crabbly

Tags: javascript, html, pdf, html-table

this my preview image of pdf which i want to print from raw html, i am using this plugin for printing pdf `https://printjs.crabbly.com/`

[image: pdf preview]

how can I change/delete the first column or from a specific column or row later? I've read the documentation but I didn't find anything about this problem

Comment: I don't know anything about that library but there is a bunch of specific printing features in CSS. You can define `@media print` media queries that define style properties only for printing. There you could exclude the first column of a table like this: `td:first-child { display: none; }`.

Comment: ok @lupz i will try it